# php login script works locally but not on host

Tags: php, mysql, login-script

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'db.php';
include 'header.html'; 

if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['email'])) {
  header("location:profile.php");

} elseif(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  $pass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));

  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, email, pass FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND pass='$pass'");

  $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
  $id = $row['id'];
  $email1 = $row['email'];
  $name = $row['name'];

  $num = mysql_num_rows($sql);
  if($num == 1) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email1;
    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;
    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET lastlogin=NOW() WHERE email='$email1'");

    header("location:profile.php");

  } else {
    echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
    echo "<p>Sorry! Either your account could not be found or you have entered the wrong email or password. Please try again.</p>";
  }
}
?>
```

This script works perfectly in my localhost environment but when uploaded to host, it does not go to the profile.php after logging in. Also, it doesn't redirect to profile.php if the session is set or not empty. Any ideas?

And second question, is my code correct for updating the 'lastlogin' to the current time? What does the database structure have to be for this? It is not updating in my database.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please type `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of the script. You'll see what's going on at least

Comment: `NOW()` returns date & time in this format: "2006-04-12 13:47:36". I think this is what you need.

Comment: @metal_fan did that but no errors reported.
FakeHeal thanks will keep testing that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out with an extensive search. The headers were already being sent with the

```
include header.html
```

line so it could not perform the

```
header(location: profile.php)
```

line. I had never heard of this issue before until now. So to resolve this issue, I just moved

```
<?php
...
include header.html
?>
```

to the bottom of the php code right before the HTML starts. Now the include header line can do it's thing and then the header will still be loaded for the page.

Thanks for all your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

your code is very ok for updating the lastlogin, but what is the error you get? please give what type of error you get on this. logically your code seems to be right, it may be some syntax error. add error_reporting(E_ALL) on top of your page and see what error is occurred actually.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. After logging in, it stays on this login page rather than going to the profile page. On my localhost, it goes to the profile page. Using bluehost

Comment: try <script type="text/javascript"> window.location("profile.php"); </script> not the header.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("location: profile.php");
                ^ //space should present because in some host environment it creates problem
```

Comment: actully the full URI should be used

Comment: there is no need for full URI if the file is on same server. @Dagon

Comment: not true, as the [header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) manual page says: "Note:

HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself: "

Comment: I don't think any browsers enforce that requirement. And if the browser did, it would fail on localhost, too. None of these answers seem to be addressing why the script works on his local server and fails in the hosted environment.

Comment: added the space...still no go

Comment: Ok I was able to find the error: `PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ****/header.html:11) in ****/login.php` ....Line 11 is a meta tag for description and somehow that is causing an issue. I commented the include header.html line out and it works fine. The top of the header files includes: `<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport' />
    <meta content='' name='description' />
    <meta content='' name='author' />'

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting to the login script from a form using most likely POST, shouldn't you use $_POST[''] instead of $_SESSION?

Just a thought.

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the form part. It is directly below this script and I have the form action to PHP SELF so it checks to see if the POST is not empty and then will run the login check and put the data into a session

Answer (score 0):

Always use `exit();` after `header` redirection